# Android: TranslateAnimation on a Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-animation, translate-animation

I have a android.graphics.Bitmap object that I draw on my canvas, what I am trying to do is animate it from position x,y to position x1, y1. So after looking through the Animation library I figured I could use the TranslateAnimation to do the animation how ever the Bitmap object does not have a "startAnimation" method. So how do I animate my bitmap? Do I need to wrap it in some other object?

Comment: The Animations are used for view objects. To translate/transform a bitmap you are drawing on a canvas you'll have to create your own animation algoritms (unless you want the entire view containing the canvas to animate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set it to an `ImageView` and animate the `ImageView` instead.

EDIT:  Now that I think about it, you should be displaying the bitmap through some view anyway.  Tween animations can be applied to any visible view, so whatever is displaying the Bitmap, just animate that.

Alternatively, you can extend a `View` and create a custom view.  Use the `canvas.translate(toX, toY)` method to shift the canvas and draw the bitmap.

Comment: So right now I have a custom View and in the OnDraw I am drawing a bunch of Bitmaps. If I change those bitmaps to ImageView how do I draw the ImageView's where I want them to be?

Comment: Draw them how?  You can place `ImageViews` anywhere you want initially just like any other `View`.  When you make your tween animation, you can choose to move is `n` number of pixels in x/y positions or a percentage based off either the `ImageView`'s location itself or it's parent.

Comment: Okay let me try this out, I will get back with you.

Answer (score -1):

DeeV says right thing - how your bitmap shown for user? It should be `ImageView`, with set `BitmapDrawable`, and for this view you can start animation.